# How to use only TinyMCE WYSWYG Core Plan

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I have registered for https://www.tiny.cloud/ but by default it gave me 1 month FREE Trial of premium features. I don't want to use any of this feature. If I implement this my client will use  these features and after 1 m he will ask. How can convert my free trial to basic Tiny Core which is open source for ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API key will convert to the free version automatically. If you are just using the community features you will be good to go! No need to change or do anything.

Of course, you might want to try the premium features during the 30-day trial to see if they are useful and valuable to your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Now the API enables all features.Which I don't want to show to client.

Comment: You can configure TinyMCE with whichever plugins you like. Just pick the non-premium ones and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should go to Github and clone/download the [open source project](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce)